# How to fix "open: No such file or directory" error(The file actually exists) after successfully using CMakeLists to make

Tags: c++, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install a motor driver C++ driver library from "https://github.com/barulicm/PiPCA9685"

I followed the README guide to use CMakeLists to build the library in "build" folder. Since there are some error occurred in the python part and I only need C++ part, I deleted the python part in CMakeLists.

I installed Ubuntu-mate on Raspberry Pi and "uname -a" gives "Linux raspi-desktop 4.15.0-1037-raspi2 #39-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed May 15 20:17:07 UTC 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux"

The file type generated by "make" command is  "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=63902bc89b28eaccea17c072a287c89020927f4d, not stripped"
and when I try to "./filename", the terminals shows"open: No such file or directory"

Previously, I followed the same procedure to generate executable file(The procedure is :cmake,make,./filename) The file generated is executable and its file typle is "ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=5bfba81687467450b832e6eae79a02978714772b, not stripped"

I found out that the difference between those two files is not executable one is "EABI5 version 1(SYSV)" and executable one is "EABI5 version 1(GNU/Linux)"

I googled the difference and don't know whether this is the reason that cause "No such file or directory"

I'm new to C++ and it will help me a lot if you give me some suggestions. Thank you!

Modified CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(PiPCA9685 VERSION 1.0.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/modules")


#

#

find_package(WiringPi REQUIRED)
include_directories(${WiringPi_INCLUDE_DIRS})





include_directories(include)


#
#

add_library(PiPCA9685 src/PCA9685.cpp)
target_link_libraries(PiPCA9685 ${WiringPi_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET PiPCA9685 PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set_target_properties(PiPCA9685 PROPERTIES VERSION ${PiPCA9685_VERSION} SOVERSION ${PiPCA9685_VERSION})


#

#

set(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR "include")
set(INSTALL_LIBS_DIR "lib")
set(INSTALL_STATIC_DIR "lib/static")
set(INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR "bin")
set(INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR "${INSTALL_LIBS_DIR}/PiPCA9685/cmake")

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
    cmake/PiPCA9685Config.cmake.in
        PiPCA9685Config.cmake
    INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/PiPCA9685
    PATH_VARS INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR
)

install(
    TARGETS PiPCA9685
    EXPORT PiPCA9685Targets
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${INSTALL_LIBS_DIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${INSTALL_STATIC_DIR}
)

install(
    DIRECTORY include/PiPCA9685
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

install(
    EXPORT PiPCA9685Targets
    FILE PiPCA9685Targets.cmake
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR}
)

install(
    FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/PiPCA9685Config.cmake"
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIG_DIR}
)
```

Comment: Yes, the file indeed exists. It should be an executable file so I can use "./filename" to execute it. I think there might be something wrong with the file type.

Comment: Check again the path where you trying to open file.

Comment: Yes, I used "ls" and "pwd" to ensure that I'm in the folder which contains object file.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your interest in PiPCA9685! And welcome to C++!

The error message "open: No such file or directory" is actually a message from the library, so your program is running. (My bad for not putting clearer error messages in this project).

The real problem is that the library is trying to open the linux device path "/dev/i2c-1" so it can talk over I2C to the PCA9685 driver.

I've not personally used I2C in Ubuntu-Mate on the Pi, but after some quick searching it looks like Ubuntu-Mate installs without I2c enabled by default. Hopefully something like the answer in this post can help you enable I2C so that the "/dev/i2c-1" path exists.
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/enable-i2c-on-ubuntu-mate-raspberry-pi-3

Comment: Hi Matt Barulic, thanks for your help and sharing of your library! Sorry It takes so long to reply since I didn't log in to stack overflow recently.
At that time I was in a rush to make every thing work, so I just switch back to Raspbian and it works fine in Raspbian. I think "Enable I2c" should be the solution of this problem.